# In OOP, should dependencies hold a reference to their parent?

Tags: php, oop, dependencies, associations

I have an Order object to represent a Prospective Order/Receipt. This is an entity. It has an identity.

I have a Writer object to read the Order object's properties and display it nicely.

It is a bit of a chore to have individual getters for all the pieces of the Client's Billing Details.

So, I am thinking of letting the Writer object get a Client's Billing Details Value Object  from the Order object. (I guess the Client's Billing Details Value Object is called a 'dependency' - correct me if i am wrong)

Now, if I do this, I'd like this dependency to 'know' if the raw persistent data changes

i.e. if countryId changes from '214' to '35'

So that the depency can return the new countryAsPrettyString 'Mexico', say, instead of the old value for 'Ecuador'.

So I guess I would have a factory method in the Order Object and can inject the Order Object into the Client's Billing Details Value Object's constructor so the Billing Details Object always derives it properties from the Order's raw persistent data properties.

**Is your reaction to this plan of action:**

A: Blimey that's obvious this is pretty much the only way to do it

or

B: My Gosh! Put aside some time for some serious headaches in a few months time - you'll create a tangle of associations - i feel for you.

or
C: [Other]

---

I am asking cos this seems like a bi-directional association to me.

The Order *has* a Billing Details Object

and

The Billing Details Object *has* the Order

and i have read that bi-directional associations are bad OOP practice.

Comment: Is there a duplication of data between the Order and Billing objects? If so is there a chance they can be different?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You want to print out an Order. To do so you need to print out the billing address, which is stored in a BillingDetails object, which is a property of the Order object. Is that right? What's the problem? That the Order also has a billing address? If so, and you want to use the Order's billing address, why are you messing around with the BillingDetails at all?

Comment: Thanks. Yes: I need to print out the billing address, which are currently sored as individual properties of the Order object and am considering grouping them into a BillingDetails object, which would be a property of the Order object. I guess by the "What's the problem" question - this is not abnormal. Re: "why are you messing around with the BillingDetails at all" - I think its cos I have an urge to keep all those together as a concept so the related methods don't make the OrderObject become vast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest you create an Address class. Your Order object can have two properties, BillingAddress and ShippingAddress, if you need both. You have a Writer class to create the view for the Order. Create an AddressWriter class to create a view for Address objects. Then you can do something like this:

```
public function printOrder($order)
{
    // print order stuff here...

    $addressWriter = new AddressWriter();

    echo "<h1>Billing Address</h1>";
    $addressWriter->printAddress($order->getBillingAddress);

    echo "<h1>Shipping Address</h1>";
    $addressWriter->printAddress($order->getShippingAddress);

    // print more order stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I know exactly what you are asking, but this may be of help:

[Change bidirectional association to unidirectional](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/change-bidirectional-association-to-unidirectional)

And this:

[Change unidirectional association to bidirectional](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/change-unidirectional-association-to-bidirectional)

Comment: thanks - these are helpful links. What a great site that is. Sticking it into my faves.

Answer (score 0):

All this started because "It is a bit of a chore to have individual getters for all the pieces of the Client's Billing Details.".

I don't know how exactly your classes are implemented, but would it be possible to use PHP's [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to automatically build those getters?

What if you were to set a convention that getBillingWhatever in Order will return $billing->getWhatever() and implement __call to provide this functionality?

Comment: Its great to bounce off you guys. I had not even noticed that I was motivated by "chore to have individual getters for all the pieces of the Client's Billing Details.". 

I suppose I prefer to hard code the boiler plate getters and setters cos I like clicking on the method name in my Dev IDE to navigate thru the source code. Like a Medieval King, "Magic Confuses and Scares Me". Also I find it easier to understand Object->getCountryAsPrettyName than Object->getProperty('CountryAsPrettyName');

but i take your point - that may just solve my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Having child class holds reference to a parent class tightens coupling. If it has to be done, I will suggest you make the parent an interface, and have the child referring to the interface. Or you can try to pass the relevant information to the child class through an associative array or a data container.